# Как решить проблему с меняющимся в зависимости от ширины window содержимым HTML-элемента?

Tags: javascript, html

Возникла проблема с кнопками. Их внешний вид меняется при определённой ширине window, но при загрузке страницы возникает короткая задержка, и сперва отображается первый вариант, а потом правильный. Как решить?

```
$(function () {

window.addEventListener('resize', changeBtn);

changeBtn();
```

});

```
function changeBtn() {
const login = $('.btn-login');
const register = $('.btn-register');

if (window.innerWidth < 992) {
    login.html(`<img src="img/sign-in.svg" alt="Sign In">`).addClass('btn-round').removeClass('btn-empty');
    register.html(`<img src="img/sign-up.svg" alt="Sign Up">`).addClass('btn-round').removeClass('btn-filled');
} else {
    login.html(`<span>Sign in</span>`).removeClass('btn-round').addClass('btn-empty');
    register.html(`<span>Sign up</span>`).removeClass('btn-round').addClass('btn-filled');
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Где находится этот скрипт? В конце страницы или в начале?

Comment: Отдельным файлом подключен в конце

Comment: А надо в начале подключать. В head.

Comment: Не помогло :( Ни подключение файла, ни вынос скрипта в тэг

Comment: @LilithLamber , надо чтобы код кнопки появлялся не заранее, а в ответ на событие onload. Тогда скрипт, выводящий этот код сделает его правильным, а перед этим ничего не будет отображаться.